# SWR "post-closing" 'aftermath" comments after an argument

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider the final (often rather desultory) addendum or comments made (by one side or the other) after an issue is decided, after an argument is complete.

So, it could be a statement of success (whether snipey or kind), an acceptance and admission of defeat (again whether angry or accepting).

What's the SW for that?

Note that there are **plenty of SWs** for other "phases" of argumentation.  For example, it's clear what "closing comments" ("last chance to wrap before the final decision") or "preamble" is. There are also SWs for witty parts of arguments, silly parts of arguments, and so on.

What do you call the "after-resolution" ejaculations?  Cheers

Comment: You're asking for a single word, but you refer to "closing comments" as a single word too. Is a single phrase acceptable?

Comment: Hi s++.  In general on SWRs, if you think of a great phrase, don't hesitate to put it forward. Often the outcome on SWRs is "there is no such word, but consider..."  SWRs are chatty generally.  Enjoy!

Comment: Ah, okay. I can't re-check now as am on phone, but it was my understanding that the "phrase-requests" tag was for when you are open to either a word or a phrase and the SWR tag was for when you wanted strictly a single word. Thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 3):

If a phrase will suffice, I would call desultory addendums like these *parting blows* or *parting shots*.

> **parting shot**
>   A final insult or last word in an argument, as in
>   *As she stalked out, Jane hurled as a parting shot, "And I quit!"*
>
> Source: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/parting+shot)

This can be used by either side. It tends to be used (as the name would suggest) when the person is actually physically leaving, but I've heard it used colloquially in situations similar to what you describe.

If someone is keen to make these comments, you say they *want to have the last word* or *want to get the last word in*, particularly if they are just making snippy remarks for the sake of it after the issue has already been resolved.

> **have the final/last word**
>   1. to say the last statement in a discussion or argument
>   *Tim can't bear to lose an argument. He always has to have the last word.*
>
> Source: [thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+the+last+word)

Comment: Very nice! both these concepts are right in there... nice

Answer (score 1):

**Sequela** may be used with respect to arguments:
[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sequela):

> 1
>   :  an aftereffect of a disease, condition, or injury
>   2
>   :  a secondary result